# GUI over GitLab CI Environment Deployments With Multiple Instances?

Tags: deployment, gitlab, release, environments, spinnaker

Let's say I have a SaaS style project (similar to Databricks).  We may make release 2.0.0 of this project, have automated testing and deployment to dev, automated promotion to nonprod, etc.

In production, I may have 200 **instances** of it running though.

What is the best way using GitLab CI to manage 200 instances/production environments? Obviously you wouldn't want 200 branches with deployments controlled by merges/etc... I assume.

How can you get a good overview over all of these environments and ensure they're deployed completely/view their versions and roll-out progress, ensure smoke tests completed for a successful pipeline/etc?

Its been implied to me that Spinnaker may be a good tool to plug this gap.  Can someone explain how that is if so?  Are there any better options?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the GitLab Operations Dashboard feature (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/operations_dashboard/)

There is a screenshot on that page, too, so you can get an idea of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It caps out at a very small number of projects though and its only personal / user specific.  Its not very useful for a company/team at any scale (yet).  I do know that they are working on scaling it though for greater purposes :).  So, fingers crossed for the future!

Comment: Got it, thanks for the data!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding modern CD tools, such as Spinnaker, Argo, Flux, Jenkins X (depending on your stack and use case - most are k8s specific) - they will help you with roll-out of any specific code base (set of artifacts) to a large number of nodes / instances. However, they wouldn't help you with versioning or keeping track of versioning. Essentially, they would help you to deploy whichever version you tell them to deploy to a large scale.

I'm currently working on a project - https://relizahub.com - which integrates with any CI/CD solution to solve the problem of versioning there. Here's my latest demo video on approvals across different environments - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzdZjMby6Is. It may help with a versioning issue and seeing what version you have at which instance and when it was deployed.